# Insert one table record into other

Tags: sql, insert, copy, record

```
Table Book
{
bookno, bookname, authorname
}
Table IssuedBook
{
rollno, bookno, bookname, authorname
}
```

I want to insert 'rollno' by value in IssuedBook table and copy the record from Book table into IssuedBook by specifying the 'bookno'.
What must be the SQL query corresponding to this?
I have tried some queries(but in vain) like:

```
INSERT INTO IssuedBook values ('09222') SELECT * FROM Book WHERE bookno='123';
```

Note: No column allow NULL key. So if I do this in two steps then there will be error.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the value of `rollno` along with your `select` statement to which the result/s will be inserted on table `IssuedBook`.

```
INSERT  INTO IssuedBook (rollno, bookno, bookname, authorname)
SELECT  '09222' rollno, bookno, bookname, authorname
FROM    Book
WHERE   bookno = '123'
```

Comment: yes it does not. `rollno` is the `select` statement is just an alias. try to execute the query.

Comment: SELECT '09222', bookno, bookname, authorname


         .....This statement is also working fine.. Any difference between the two statements?